Spring deserialize List<Resource>
I have a springboot project with openApi for generate specification, i try to make an endpoint which receive many files but i have a spring error.
JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<org.springframework.core.io.Resource>` from Object value

my openApi spec:
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                attachedFiles:
                  type: array
                  items:
                    type: string
                    format: binary
              required:
                - attachedFiles

Do you know how to make possible the deserialization of a List

It is certainly possible to deserialize a list using Jackson.
But you will need to implement your own deserializer for org.springframework.core.io.Resource.  This could be a binary stream (your OpenAPI spec even says this), so how do you propose representing this in JSON?  Perhaps Base64 encoded?

I don't want to get Resource from Json but from a file give in RequestBody. Like a file that comes from a dropzone of a form.
